# Cannot chroot due to "Input/output error" - file and disk seem OK

Tags: chroot, fsck, smartctl

I am trying to repair a non-booted Arch installation after a computer crash during an update (worst of times).  However, `chroot` fails.

Tried this:

```
# mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/arch
# cd /mnt/arch
# mount --bind /dev dev
# mount --bind /proc proc
# mount --bind /sys sys
# chroot . bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘bin/bash’: Input/output error
Exit 126
```

The file can actually be read OK:

```
# sha256sum  bin/bash
3695f983ad6a1387826f769b96488f24e3635a1501fe89c96d3eadfa4e04caf7  bin/bash
```

Let's check the filesystem and disk

```
# umount sys
# umount proc
# umount dev
# cd ..
# umount arch
# fsck -f /dev/sdb2
```

(NO ERRORS REPORTED)

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sdb
```

(NO ERRORS REPORTED)

The disk is an SSD and not very old.  `dmesg` does not show any relevant kernel error messages.

PS / EDIT:

```
# chroot . bin/bash
```

and

```
# chroot . /bin/bash
```

Give the same error as they address the same file.  It exists (see `sha256sum` command).

EDIT 2: @roaima pointed out to check the libraries:

```
# ldd bin/bash 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff16563000)
    libreadline.so.8 => /lib64/libreadline.so.8 (0x00007f6483600000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f64835f8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6483430000)
    libtinfo.so.6 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f64833f8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6483778000)
```

Then check these in `/mnt/arch`:

```
# ls -ld ./lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./lib64/ld-2.29.so ./usr/lib/libdl.so.2 ./usr/lib/libdl-2.29.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  0 Jun 23 10:33 ./lib64/ld-2.29.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 23 10:33 ./lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.29.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun 23 10:33 ./usr/lib/libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.29.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jun 23 10:33 ./usr/lib/libdl-2.29.so
```

So, the most basic system libraries are 0-sized due to a crash in the most inappropriate moment thinkable - an update of `glibc`.

Comment: Is that bin/bash inside the chroot?

Comment: @stolenmoment Yes it is.

Comment: Check all the dynamically linked libraries too

Comment: @roaima Thanks, that's the problem nailed down. I used `tar --wildcards -xvJf var/cache/pacman/pkg/glibc-2.29-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz usr/lib/\*` in `/mnt/arch` to fix. Wanna put it into an Answer or shall I?

Comment: I'm not going to get time so please do go ahead and write an answer

Answer (score 2):

After the recommendation by roaima I checked the (shared object) libraries of the Arch Linux system I wanted to `chroot` into, especially those used by the `bin/bash` binary.  These were broken; more specifically, 0-size files `/mnt/arch/lib64/ld-2.29.so`, `/mnt/arch/usr/lib/libdl-2.29.so` etc.

In order to restore the files inside the broken Arch Linux, I searched (on the Internet) for the names of the package files that the broken libraries are contained in.  These files were still in the package manager's package cache, i.e. in

```
/mnt/arch/var/cache/pacman/pkg/glibc-2.29-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

I unpacked the file (still before `chroot`ing) like this:

```
cd /mnt/arch
tar --wildcards -xvJf var/cache/pacman/pkg/glibc-2.29-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz usr/lib/\*
```

which unpacked all files matching "usr/lib/*" from the package file.

After this, I could indeed `chroot` as intended.  The first thing I did was `pacman -Syu` to complete the failed update.

**Side note:** Arch Linux uses BSD `tar` to pack/unpack the package files, and I used GNU `tar`.  This may (generally) sometimes create problems because GNU `tar` does not handle (unpack and set) special file attributes which BSD `tar` (`bsdtar`) does preserve/set. Since those library files (apparently) do not need any attributes I was fine, though.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't it be `/bin/bash` ? If not, maybe some process is using some files which are needed, that can be examined by `lsof`

Comment: No, a relative path works if the file exists. Using the full path gives the same error. Edited my question accordingly.